# What is the number of unque subsets of a set with `n` elements

Tags: combinatorics

eg: If I have $3$ elements in a set {$1,2,3$}, the number of ways I can make a subset out of them of the following type is:
{$1$}, {$2$}, {$3$}, {$1,2$}, {$1,3$}, {$2,3$}, {$1,2,3$}

Comment: I know this can;t be given by 2^n

Comment: The number of subsets of cardinality $k$ inside a set of cardinality $n$ is $\binom{n}{k}:=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for though.

Comment: If I choose 2 I can't choose 1 for the second element in the 2-element-subset. (Can't choose previous)

Comment: The answer _is_ $2^n$. Order does not matter and the empty set is a subset too.

Comment: "Can't choose previous"? Why not? What is true is that a set is the same regardless of the sequence in which you name the elements: 1 and then 2 is the same as 2 and then 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The number of subsets of a set of cardinality $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62172/the-number-of-subsets-of-a-set-of-cardinality-n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is $2^n$ because you are missing the empty set. Here $n=3,2^n=2^3=8$ total subsets.

$$P(\{1,2,3\})=\Big\{\emptyset,\{1,2,3\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\}\Big\}$$

Comment: If not considering complete set { 1 , 2 , 3 } as a subset, then 2^n -1