# $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}=2^n$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a set of n elements:{1,2,....,n}

I have to form a subset of k elements which can be done in $n \choose k$ ways.

$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}$ would be the total no of subsets with k elements that can be formed.

But then my professor says $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}=2^n$.

I'm not looking for a reasoning based on the binomial expansion because using the expansion formula this makes sense.

I'm looking for more of an intuitive explanation to this.

Comment: The sum counts the number of total ways to choose elements from the set. For every element, it can either be chosen or not chosen, so $2$ states can be applied to it. There are $n$ elements, so there are $2^n$ states for the entire set.

Comment: @David Dong....this is the same kind of rationale my professor  expressed but....consider that my n=4 and I make a one element subset in which I make a choice to cho0se an element or not and then make a two element subset in which I make a choice whether I choose an element or not and then I have to make the choice for 3 element and 4 element subsets....which would be more than $2^n$...I'm getting confused in the understanding....

Comment: "would be the total number of subsets with $k$ elements **for any $k$ from $0$ to $n$** that can be formed" - hence the total number of subsets, aka $2^n$

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62172/742113

Comment: "...which would be more than $2^n$": run an experiment - take the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ and start to count subsets of size zero $\{\}$, of size one $\{a\}$, $\{b\}$, $\{c\}$, $\{d\}$, of size two $\{a,b\}$, $\{a,c\}$, $\{a,d\}$, $\{b,c\}$, $\{b,d\}$, $\{c,d\}$ and so on. It will be exactly $2^4$ in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every subset of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ can be represented by a vector $A$ of size $n$ with entries ${0,1}$.

$A_i = 0$ means the subset does not contain $i$.
$A_i = 1$ means the subset contains $i$.

The collection of all choices of $A$ has one-one correspondence with the collection of all subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. The number of ways to choose $A$ is $2^n$.

Comment: So m looking at all the possible A's that can be created from the n element  set....?

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider this explanation:

Consider having a binary number of $n$ digits, where every digit can be $0$ or $1$:

$$d_1d_2d_3.....d_n$$

As you have two options for every digit, the total number of options to this number is $2*2*2*..*2$ ($n$ times) which means $2^n$.

On the other hand, lets calculate the number of options for this number in a different way.

Will you agree that the group of options of this number can be determined by the number of $1$'s it has? meaning that:

$$\#_{d_1d_2..d_n}=|d_1d_2..d_n\;\text{has $0$ ones}|+|d_1d_2..d_n\;\text{has $1$ ones}|+....+|d_1d_2..d_n\;\text{has $n$ ones}|$$

This is true because we divided all options to different groups, while each option has exactly one and unique group.

Then, by agreeing to that, you get that:

$$\#_{d_1d_2..d_n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose{k}}$$

While $k$ is the number of ones in an $n$ digits binary number